# Brackets won't install Emmet plugin

Tags: editor, adobe-brackets

I have just installed the text editor Adobe Brackets to try it out and my first action was to install my favourite plugin, Emmet. I was frustrated to find that the installation failed. I have tried downloading the emmet zip file and dragging into the Extension Manager but the result is the same. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Brackets and restarting Windows. I am not prepared to use Brackets without Emmet so how can I fix this?

I am using Windows 10 and I note that Brackets will only install a 32-bit version. Brackets version is Release 1.12 build 1.12.0-17621 (release d3b783b99)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I appear to have solved the problem. I removed all the other newly installed plugins and then tried to install Emmet - this time with success. There must have been a conflict, tho not sure with what.

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

When the installation fails. Which problem do you have? (Error code or something?)

Have you even tried to run Brackets as Administrator?

Have you followed the guide in GitHub for Emmet in Brackets? 
https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet#installation

Comment: My query was a year ago. I have since given up on Brackets and moved to VSCode which IMHO is a superior editor

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I just closed Brackets and then re-opened it by right clicking the icon and opening as an Administrator. Once Brackets is open again go as normal to install Emmet from Extension Manager. Problem Solved!!!!   :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into this issue and the other methods don't work, as they did for me, try this.

Attempt to install Emmet from the Extension Manager and while it's attempting, type in the URL referenced in the downloading window. This will begin the ZIP download on your own machine. Then you can drag the ZIP onto the Extension Manager "Drag .zip file here" section to install.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a matter of having no other extension installed. Pretty lightweight, the brackets AND with the necessary plugs (swatch, SCSS, classhint, lint), I'll keep using it. Just saying..

Comment: I've switched to VSCode - much better!

Answer (score 0):

http://s3.amazonaws.com/extend.brackets/brackets-emmet/brackets-emmet-1.2.2.zip

Open this link and download the zip file.

then drag the zip file from windows explorer into extension manager in brackets

Comment: Thanks but long since moved on to VsCode

Comment: yeah same here, all the hassle wasn't worth it.